# Showing that $X\in\mathbb{M}_{m, n}(A)$ is equivalent to a matrix with certain "diagonal" form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

Let $A$ be a ring, $2\leq m$, and $\lambda\in A$. For $i,j\in[1,m]$ such that $i\ne j$, define
$$B_{ij}(\lambda):=I_m+\lambda E_{ij},$$
where $E_{ij}$ is the $m\times m$ matrix having a $1$ in its $(i,j)$ entry and $0$ everywhere else.

I would like to prove the following assertion:

> Let $X:=(\xi_{ij})_{ij}$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over a ring $A$ and
> $2\leq m$. Suppose there exists some $1\leq i\leq n$ such that
> $\xi_{i1}$ is invertible. Then
> $$\left(\prod_{k=0}^{m-2}B_{(m-k)1}(\mu_{m-k})\right)B_{1i}(\lambda)X\left(\prod_{j=2}^nB_{1j}(\nu_j)\right)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0   &  & \\  \vdots & &Y &\\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$$
> where $Y$ is $(m-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix over $A$.

By multiplying $X$ by $B_{1i}(\lambda)$ (by appropriately picking $\lambda$) we get a matrix whose $(1,1)$ entry is $1$. Multiplying $B_{1i}(\lambda)X$ by $B_{21}(\mu_2)$, for some specially picked $\mu_2$, gives a matrix whose $(1,1)$ entry is $1$ and $(2,1)$ entry is $0$. And so on. The right hand multiplication proceeds in the same manner with only difference that it turns $(1,j)$ entries $0$.

This is easy to understand. However, I am having difficulty proving this result. Presumably the proof proceeds by induction; so let me try that. Let's fix $m=2$ and induct on $n$. A series of calculations show that the above result holds for $2\times 2$ matrices. Suppose it holds for all  $2\times n$ matrices over $A$ and let us prove it for $2\times n+1$ matrices.

Let $X$ be a $2\times(n+1)$ matrix over $A$. At this point, it is not clear to me how I can utilize the inductive hypothesis here. In fact I am not sure if the proof strategy is appropriate. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think that you have written the assertion that you are trying to prove. I suspect that you mean to add "there exist $\lambda, \mu_s, \nu_s$  and a matrix $Y$ such that" before the big equality. As it stands it's not true.